# Help with an integral with some assumptions on the parameter

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have the integral $$\int_{t=1}^{u}\min(1,t^{\,n-1}(u-1)^{n-1})\,dt .$$ with $1 \leq u \leq 2$ Can somebody kindly help with splitting the interval of integration $(1,u)$ so as to get rid of the $min$ function, or just plug it in Mathematica?  Since $1 \leq t \leq u$, $$ 1\leq t^{n-1}(u-1)^{n-1} \implies 1\leq u^{n-1}(u-1)^{n-1 }. $$ .I don't know what to do further. I wonder if one can get the steps by writing it in wolfram cloud,I tried in the free version but didn't get anything. I inputted the folowing code:
`Integrate[Min[1, t^(n - 1) (u - 1)^(n - 1)], {t, 1, u},Assumptions->1 <=u<=2]` . Thank you for any hints/suggestions

Comment: What about parameter `n`? Perhaps positive integer?

Comment: yes indeed ,$n$ is a positive integer

Answer (score 2):

The expression `1== t(u-1)` determines where `Min[1,(t(u-1))^(n-1)]` splits:

`ContourPlot` shows the regions

```
Show[{ContourPlot[1 == t (u - 1), {u, 1, 2}, {t, 1, u}, 
   ContourStyle -> Red, FrameLabel -> {u, t}, 
   GridLines -> {{GoldenRatio}, {GoldenRatio}}]
  , Plot[u, {u, 1, 2}], 
  Graphics[{Text["Min[...]==(t(u-1))^(n-1)", {1.5, 1.2} ], 
    Text["Min[...]==1", {1.8, 1.6} ], 
    Text[Style["t==\!\(\*FractionBox[\(1\), \(u - 1\)]\)", Red], {1.8,
       1.4} ] }]}, PlotRange -> {1, 2}]
```

[image]

Depending on the value of `u` the integral evaluates to

```
Which[
1<u<GoldenRatio,((-1 + u)^(-1 + n) (-1 + u^n))/n,
GoldenRatio<u<2,(1 - n - (-1 + u)^n - n u + n u^2)/(n (-1 + u)) 
]
```

Comment: Can you explain how `GoldenRatio` is derived? TIA.

Comment: Solution of `u (u - 1) == 1`

Comment: How does this equation appear?

Comment: intersection of blue and red line in `ContourPlot`

Comment: Please,  don't avoid of answer.

Comment: All that is not so simple. For example, `n=3;PiecewiseExpand[Min[1,(t*(u-1))^(n-1)]]` produces $$\begin{cases}
 1 & t^2 u^2-2 t^2 u+t^2\geq 1 \\
 t^2 (u-1)^2 & \text{True}
\end{cases} .$$

Comment: more general `Simplify[PiecewiseExpand[Min[1, (t*(u - 1))^(n - 1)]], 
 Element[n, PositiveIntegers] ]` produces
 $\begin{cases}
 1 & (t (u-1))^{n-1}\geq 1 \\
 (t (u-1))^{n-1} & \text{True}
\end{cases}$ 
in good agreement with my answer!

Comment: I repeat I don't see `GoldenRatio` in the above expand, Deep regard.

Comment: @user64404 A different way to state it is that one solves for the intersection of the curves`t==u` and `t==1/(u-1)`. That latter is where the min crosses from 1 to `(t (u-1))^(n-1)`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thank you for your helpful assistence.

Answer (score 2):

Amplifying on partial answer by user64494,

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

The assumptions do not simplify the integrand

```
expr = Assuming[{1 <= t <= u, 1 <= u <= 2,
   Element[n, PositiveIntegers]},
  Min[1, t^(n - 1) (u - 1)^(n - 1)] //
   Simplify]

(* Min[1, (t (-1 + u))^(-1 + n)] *)
```

Generating the sequence for integer values of `n`

```
seq = Table[
   Assuming[{1 <= t <= u, 1 <= u <= 2},
     Integrate[expr, {t, 1, u}]] // FullSimplify,
   {n, 1, 10}];
```

For `n > 1` the integrals are [`Piecewise`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) expressions with the form of the results changing at `u == (1 + Sqrt[5])/2`, for example

```
seq[[2]] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Since,

```
GoldenRatio // FunctionExpand

(* 1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5]) *)
```

The transition occurs at `u == GoldenRatio`

```
seq = seq /. Sqrt[5] -> 2 GoldenRatio - 1;
```

The closed-form of the sequence for `1 < u <= GoldenRatio` is

```
expr2 = Assuming[1 < u <= GoldenRatio,
  FindSequenceFunction[seq // Simplify, n]]

(* -(((-1 + u)^n - ((-1 + u) u)^n)/(n (-1 + u))) *)
```

The closed-form for `GoldenRatio < u <= 2` is

```
expr3 = Assuming[GoldenRatio < u <= 2,
  FindSequenceFunction[seq // Simplify, n] // FullSimplify]

(* (1 - (-1 + u)^n + n (-1 + (-1 + u) u))/(n (-1 + u)) *)
```

The expressions are equivalent for `n == 1`

```
expr2 == expr3 /. n -> 1 // Simplify

(* True *)
```

The piecewise expression is piecewise continuous at the transition

```
expr2 == expr3 /. u -> GoldenRatio // Simplify

(* True *)
```

The integral is then

```
(int[u_, n_] = Piecewise[{
     {expr2, 1 < u <= GoldenRatio},
     {expr3, GoldenRatio < u <= 2}}]) // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Comment: Can't reproduce it on my comp equipped with 13.0 on Windows 10: `expr2 = Assuming[1 < u <= GoldenRatio, 
  FindSequenceFunction[seq // Simplify, n]]` returns `FindSequenceFunction[{-1+u,1/2 (-1+u)^2 (1+u),\[Piecewise] (1+u (6+(-6+u) u))/(3-3 u) $Aborted[]
1/3 (-1+u)^2 (-1+u^3) True
....
,....`

Comment: I unsuccessfully tried `FindSequenceFunction[
 Table[Integrate[Min[1, t^(n - 1) (u - 1)^(n - 1)], {t, 1, u}, 
   Assumptions -> 
    1 < u <= 1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5]) && n \[Element] PositiveIntegers], {n, 
   1, 5}]]` which returns the input.

Comment: @user64494 - You are giving `FindSequenceFunction` a sequence which is too short. More complicated expressions require longer sequences with which to work. As in my code, use a sequence length of `10` rather than `5`.

Comment: `FindSequenceFunction[
 Table[Integrate[Min[1, t^(n - 1) (u - 1)^(n - 1)], {t, 1, u}, 
   Assumptions -> 
    1 < u <= 1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5]) && n \[Element] PositiveIntegers], {n, 
   1, 10}]]` produces `DifferenceRoot`, I repeat that your `FindSequenceFunction[seq//Simplify,n]` returns the input for me.

Comment: @user64494 - Presumably, it is due to a difference in the OS, I use v13.0 on macOS 12.1. Your `FindSequenceFunction[Table[ Integrate[Min[1, t^(n - 1) (u - 1)^(n - 1)], {t, 1, u}, Assumptions -> 1 < u <= 1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5]) && n \[Element] PositiveIntegers], {n, 1, 10}]]` evaluates to a pure function, i.e., `-(((-1 + u)^#1 - ((-1 + u)*u)^#1)/((-1 + u)*#1)) &` since `FindSequenceFunction` was not given a second argument.

Comment: +1. Indeed, `FindSequenceFunction[
 Table[Integrate[Min[1, t^(n - 1) (u - 1)^(n - 1)], {t, 1, u}, 
   Assumptions -> 
    1 < u <= 1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5]) && n \[Element] PositiveIntegers], {n, 
   1, 10}], n]` produces `-(((-1 + u)^n - ((-1 + u) u)^n)/(n (-1 + u)))`.

Comment: @bobhanlon Your solution agrees well with the solution in my answer. Additionally I'm happy to retrieve goldenratio in your attempt too.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann - yes. I previously upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment. The result of

```
Table[Integrate[Min[1, t^(n - 1) (u - 1)^(n - 1)], {t, 1, u}, 
Assumptions -> 1 <= u <= 2 ], {n, 1,5}]
```

suggests a partial answer

```
Integrate[Min[1, t^(n - 1) (u - 1)^(n - 1)], {t, 1, u}, 
Assumptions -> 1 < u <=1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5]) && n \[Element] PositiveIntegers]
```

> `1/n*(-1+u)^(n-1)*(-1+u^n)`